# Cual es la diferencia de estas 2 funciones?

Tags: c

Es que tengo tengo 2 funciones y no entiendo cual es la diferencia entre las 2

```
char **tokenizer(char *str) 
**char tokenizer(char *str)
```

Comment: ¿Seguro que es así: `**char tokenizer(char *str) `? Eso ni compila.